# GPG error "Not enough random bytes available. Please do some other work to give the OS a chance to collect more"

Tags: ubuntu, gnupg

I am using:

```
 gpg --gen-key
```

Is there a better way to create a PGP key? What does this program want? A fully slammed server?

> Not enough random bytes available.  Please do some other work to give the OS a chance to collect more

Comment: Also see [this other SO question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708334/pgp-asymmetric-not-enough-random-bytes-available-please-do-some-other-work-to

Comment: How is this a programming question? I could see it as a system administration question or an end-user software usage question, but neither of those are topical here. (Also, it's a bit sad to see the answer that makes sense on modern hardware -- using rng-tools to bridge the TRNG to /dev/random -- buried down at third place).

Comment: just use ls -R / simple. no need to install any bloatware

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can move your mouse around, browse the internet, play a game, leave your computer on overnight.  There are many many ways to generate random bytes.  You don't need to babysit the gpg process.

EDIT: I should clarify:  you don't need to pay attention or even type into the terminal that gpg is running in.  (And it's a really bad idea to type into that terminal anyway.)

If you're on a remote server, and cannot otherwise generate work, you can try this: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/stress.  **Use caution**, though.

Comment: I am using a remote server.  How lomng does it take to generate?

Comment: It's difficult to put a timeframe on it.  But you can try firing up a whole heap of different processes to load it.  A good one is the 'stress' package: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/stress

Comment: It just doesn't work. The message "Not enough random bytes available..." is continuing to appear with different values of bytes (sometimes less, sometimes more) required.

Comment: @dEfENDER it sounds like you are restarting the gpg process, if the number of bytes is going down *and* up.  You have to leave it running, while you generate more entropy.

Comment: No. I do not restarts the process. It just sometimes writes +++ and the message about data to console. If I leave the process it will do nothing. Some methods of manupulating huge data in other consoles are works sometime and it saves...

Comment: Running `ls -alR /` a couple of times did the job for me.

Answer (score 83):

Depending on your system hardware, you might have more reliable success using a bridge between the hardware TRNG (True random number generator) and the kernel entropy pool.

I have found a remarkable speed increase by using rng-tools in the universe repository, which can be installed with Synaptic or another GUI package manager, or via the command-line:

```
sudo apt-get install rng-tools
```

Comment: gpg hung for hours, no matter how much I moved the mouse, etc. Installing this package allowed gpg to finish in seconds, without moving the mouse.

Comment: Do you just have to install it, or run one of the tools while it's going?

Comment: Just installing it didn't work for me (unless I have to restart my computer first). Running the software updater seems to help sometimes, heh, heh.

Comment: Simply installing this package on ubuntu 14.04 amd64 had my `gpg --gen-key` finish in seconds as well, whereas previously it had hung for many minutes. Thanks!

Comment: this worked for me, where everything else like long find failed

Comment: .. and Run 
`sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom`
before generation!

Comment: Simply installing it worked for me. This should be the accepted answer. Thanx!!

Comment: Installing `rng-tools` and running `sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom` worked for me

Comment: On a VM, `rng-tools` will probably not be much help because it doesn't have access to the cpu's TRNG. [Use `haveged` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708334/pgp-not-enough-random-bytes-available-please-do-some-other-work-to-give-the-os/21705999#21705999)

Comment: yum install rng-tools  and sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom works for RHEL.

Answer (score 34):

Executing the following command in the background works for me:

```
sudo find / -type f | xargs grep somerandomstring > /dev/null
```

Comment: This has the potential to hang your system though. Fills up available memory quickly.

Comment: worked for me (had to execute it several times). thanks

Comment: I tried several suggestions. This was the only one that worked.

Comment: Worked for me right away, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I found that just **moving the program to the background** worked even over an ssh interface:

1. move the task to the background (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>)
2. perform a few short tasks       (`cd ~ && ./my-time-waster.sh`)
3. move the task to the foreground (`fg`)
4. wait a minute or two

*I'm using CentOS5 and CentOS6.*

Answer (score 2):

Try using `rngd`, but without the `-r /dev/random` you will often see people advise (which will lead to insecure GPG keys). On my machine, just installing `rngd` installs a daemon which fills up my entropy quickly, and securely.

Comment: I had to run rngd with `rngd -r /dev/urandom` before I used gpg in order to get it working in VirtualBox