# GPG hangs on entropy generation

Tags: ubuntu, gnupg

While attempting to generate GPG keys (using gpg --gen-key), it may hang after emitting the message:

Not enough random bytes available. Please do some other work to give
the OS a chance to collect more entropy! (Need 278 more bytes)

gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.16

Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: See duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708334/pgp-not-enough-random-bytes-available-please-do-some-other-work-to-give-the-os

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although rng-tools will work, this is not suggested since it doesn't provide real entropy. See the discussion here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnupg/+bug/706011

For users that are frustrated by this, here are some things I found helpful on a server with no mouse/desktop.

1) Go through the process of creating the GPG key. If it hangs waiting for more entropy, go to the next step.

2) You can watch how much entropy your system has by opening a terminal and type (this will look at that file every second):

```
watch -n1 cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

3) Open a third terminal to generate your entropy. You can try various things to try to boost that entropy. Here are some things that I noticed increased the entropy sufficiently to make gpg work. Note that this was somewhat random (no pun intended). Sometimes doing something would increase the entropy; but when I do it again, it does not:

Get a large file from the internet

```
wget http://us1.php.net/get/php-7.2.2.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
```

Do something that prints a lot of stuff to the terminal:

```
ls -R /
sudo find /folder/with/lots/of/files/ -type f | xargs grep 'simple string that shows up in lots of files'
```

4) If what you are doing does not increase the entropy_avail, then try something else.

Comment: may need to repeatedly download a larger file if on a cloud server, e.g. 
`wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso`

Answer (score 10):

Edit:
This advice should not be followed in general as it does not generate secure keys. See juacala's answer, or [stackoverflow.com/questions/11708334](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708334/) for details.

Turns out this is a known issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnupg/+bug/706011

I resolved it by installing rng-tools.

ie `sudo apt-get install rng-tools`

Then `gpg --gen-key` works as expected.

Comment: funnily enough, running `sudo apt-get install rng-tools` generated more entropy than any other method suggested. My gpg --gen-key had been stalled for tens of minutes and immediately finished during the installation of rng-tools. And this was after going through all of the methods listed by @juacala below (all during the during the same invocation of `gpg --gen-key`!)

Comment: According to the link quoted in the answer, you should NOT use rng-tools if you're going to use the key for real-world purposes, because it doesn't generate real entropy and your key may not be secure.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sudo apt install haveged
```

That will install `haveged` service, which collects entropy and fills `/dev/random` much more effectively. You don't need to run any additional commands after installing `haveged`, it will automatically start the service. `systemctl status haveged` to verify the service is running. You can also `cat /dev/random` to demonstrate that it can continuously provide values. In my test, `gpg --gen-key` completed in 10 seconds with `haveged` installed.

If you don't want to install anything, you can generate entropy in other ways, but it's much slower than `haveged` (about 10x slower in my tests). Run this in another terminal while `gpg --gen-key` is running:

```sh
while true; do
    # print entropy available
    cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
    # write a 1 MB stream of zeros to /tmp/foo
    # "conv=fdatasync" flushes the disk cache
    dd bs=1M count=1 if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/foo conv=fdatasync
done

# one liner
while true; do cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail; dd bs=1M count=1 if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/foo conv=fdatasync; done
```