# Cannot login to Docker account

Tags: docker, authentication

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 Server
Docker 18.3 CE
```

I am logged onto the server, from my Windows 10 laptop, using a PuTTY SSH session.

I don't have Docker on my local Windows laptop, so all the work is done on the remote server.

I can execute all Docker commands, on the remote server, using the terminal session.

However, when I try to save my image to the Docker hub, when I try to login, using:

```
docker login
```

I get the following error message:

```
error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files`
```

I did not get any error messages, when I created my image on the remote server.

I also do not see a .docker folder in the related home directory on the remote server. Any ideas?

Comment: I ran into a somewhat similar problem today while trying to run `docker login` from within a LXD/LXC container. That particular one I solved by copying `.docker/config.json` from my host over to my `$HOME/.docker/` directory within the LXD/LXC container, which I created manually. I'm currently trying to figure out another issue now, but wanted to ask if you had you tried doing this yet?

Comment: No, I sort of gave up on Windows. I am getting a new laptop tomorrow, where I will be installing Ubuntu 18 as a dual boot.

Comment: I have opened up an issue for this here https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1136. If they find a solution for this, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

Edit 2019-04-07:

As this is the currently selected answer, I think people should try @Anish Varghese solution below first as it seems to be the easiest. 
You only need to install the gnupg2 and pass packages:

> sudo apt install gnupg2 pass

If it doesn't work, then you can try my original solution here:

I had the same issue. bak2trak answer worked, but it saved credentials in clear text. Here's the solution if you want to keep them in a password store.

1) Download docker-credential-pass from https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases

2) `tar -xvf docker-credential-pass.tar.gz`

3) `chmod u+x docker-credential-pass`

4) `mv docker-credential-pass /usr/bin`

5) You will need to setup docker-credential-pass (following steps are based of https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/102#issuecomment-388634452)

5.1) install gpg and pass (`apt-get install gpg pass`)

5.2) `gpg --generate-key`, enter your information. You should see something like this:

```
pub   rsa3072 2018-10-07 [SC] [expires: 2020-10-06]
      1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF12345678
```

Copy the 123... line

5.3) `pass init 1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF12345678` (paste)

5.4) `pass insert docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check` and set the 
next password "pass is initialized" (without quotes).

5.5) `pass show docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check`. You should see pass is initialized.

5.6) `docker-credential-pass list`

6) create a ~/.docker/config.json with:

```
{
"credsStore": "pass"
}
```

7) docker login should now work

Note: If you get the error "pass store is uninitialized" in future run, run the below command (it will reload the pass store in memory):

```
pass show docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check
```

It will ask your password and it will initialize the pass store.

This is based off this discussion:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25169#issuecomment-431129898

Comment: Didn't work for me. I get the message when I try docker login:
"error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `pass store is uninitialized"

Comment: I started again after uninstalling pass and deleting the .password-store folder. Seems better now. Thanks.

Comment: @GlacialSpoon: Before calling docker login, you can try to call pass show docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check, it wil lask you for your password and it should be initialized.

Comment: @Jean-Phillipe Jodoin, thanks. It seems I have to call this periodically otherwise the login call fails to find the credentials. I read this might be something to do with the gpg cache expiring and the "pass show" wakes it up. When the server reboots I have to go back to the "pass insert" step before things work. It's not very convenient but it is allowing me to proceed.

Comment: Check the answer by Anish Varghese below, it seems to be the easiest and cleanest solution.

Comment: gpg: invalid option "--generate-key"

Comment: Can you make it more clear which values we should be changing and which we shouldn't?

Comment: Due to the answer below, this one is actually harmful at this point. It will actually keep the one below from working properly. I feel like it would be a good netizenship move to instruct people to first try the answer below

Comment: @JoePhillips: Agreed with you. Integrated his solution with citation.

Comment: I need to also follow this post: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/61064500-docker-credential-pass-does-not-work-at-all , because I was getting a StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-pass exited with "exit status 2: gpg: decryption failed: No secret key".',) after doing a docker pull. Therefore, performing a export GPG_TTY=$(tty)

Comment: Why did installing gnupg works? Without it I had to wait about 10s till login prompt, after everything seem to start instantaneously

Comment: I had to restart my VM to make this work.

Answer (score 298):

Install the following Packages in ubuntu fixed my issue

```
sudo apt install gnupg2 pass
```

Comment: didn't work for me, but also installing gpg worked: "sudo apt install gnupg2 pass gpg"

Comment: Worked for me on ubuntu 18.04 too. I only issued `sudo apt install pass`, the rest came as its dependencies

Comment: Worked for me on Unbuntu 18.04.

Comment: What is the root of the problem? and why how ``gnupg2 pass`` will fix the problem?

Comment: Worked for me at ubuntu 19.04 too

Comment: Worked for an edge device ARM64 on ubuntu 18.04 many thanks, the error was just: what is your password? then no answer at all... which was very difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me on Debian 10

Comment: This answer helped me, when I got `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password`. Just for the records

Comment: Worked for me on Linux mint 19.3. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is lovely and terrible. I don't have the proper words to express how I feel. This is MAGIC!

Comment: Worked on `debian 10.4` too

Comment: Worked on 18.04.6 LTS 64 bit, thanks! I had to restart my VM to make this work fyi.

Answer (score 55):

I faced the same issue in ubuntu 18.08 and this finally worked for me.. as a temporary solution.

I had created this folder `home/.docker/` as some solutions suggested me to create a file `config.json` and write default credentials in it i.e.

```
{
    "credsStore": "pass"
}
```

- I deleted this file `config.json`.
- Then renamed docker-credential-secretservice to something else so that it doesn't picks up this file.

  sudo mv /usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice /usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice_x

and it worked!

Comment: @Renrhaf First [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store) by default looks for "pass" where it searches in gnome key-chain and osx-keychain in OS-X . If it's not found then looks for `org.freedesktop.secrets`. Its not found for ubuntu 18 (some issues).  After renaming it (docker-credential-secretservice) to something else then it falls back to create config file by itself, You can look in home/.docker folder one config.json file would have been created.

Comment: I just encountered this issue and solved it via this method - kind of.  I installed `docker-credential-secretservice` from GH, created a `~/.docker/config.json` with content as above then tried to log in. Got an error.  Then deleted the `.docker` folder, `config.json` and the `/usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice` executable and then ran `docker login` again with success

Comment: To anyone having the same issue: Don't forget to **delete config.json** . I almost gave up on this, but it worked in the last moment, after I deleted config.json.

Comment: For me, I uninstalled `docker-compose` and then ran your `sudo mv /usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice /usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice_x` rename, it worked. Does anyone know what `docker-credential-secretservice` is used for?

Comment: docker credential store https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Comment: This solution worked for me, but it saves credentials base 64 encoded. I posted below a solution which uses pass.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151833/cannot-login-to-docker-account/52881198#52881198

Comment: it works with 'mv /usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice /usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice_x'

Comment: This solution worked for me in Linux mint 19.3.

Answer (score 23):

This work for me in my Ubuntu 18:

```
docker logout
mv ~/.docker/config.json ~/.docker/config_old.json
docker login
```

Comment: working also on MacOS BigSur

Comment: worked in ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 11):

I just deleted the ~/.docker/config.json and try the login again. It works. A new file is created.

Comment: I tried everything else in this thread and the only thing that worked for me was this one.

Answer (score 10):

This may help too, at least it did in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
wget https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases/download/v0.6.3/docker-credential-secretservice-v0.6.3-amd64.tar.gz && tar -xf docker-credential-secretservice-v0.6.3-amd64.tar.gz && chmod +x docker-credential-secretservice && mv docker-credential-secretservice /usr/local/bin/
```

https://hackernoon.com/getting-rid-of-docker-plain-text-credentials-88309e07640d  
https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases

Answer (score 7):

If apt install gnupg2 pass does not work for you, you can also install golang-docker-credential-helpers package

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem (headless Ubuntu 20, upgraded from 16,18) and none of the other answers worked for me.  Finally, after reading some of the discussions posted here I found the problem was that the **gnome-keyring** was installed but not working properly.  Since this was a headless, the correct answer was to remove gnome-keyring (since it was providing the **org.freedesktop.secrets** service) and then it worked perfectly.

```
sudo apt remove gnome-keyring golang-docker-credential-helpers
```

Comment: Thanks. Removing gnome-keyring was enough - removing golang-docker-credential-helpers would mean to remove docker-compose, too.

Answer (score 6):

For me the simplest solution was to create config.json file under .docker directory inside user home directory:

/home/.docker/config.json

Then i copied the content of this file from the server from where i was able to login to the docker hub.

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "SOMEVALUE"
                }
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.06.1-ce (linux)"
        }

}
```

Its a easy workaround, because it doesn't require you to install or update any package which we can't do easily on production servers.

Comment: Sadly, this is the only workaround that has worked for me... at least it's possible to use an access token instead of your account's pwd.

Comment: The path "~/home/.docker/config.json" seems so wrong. You probably meant "~/.docker/config.json"

Comment: Thanks for poinitng it out, upadated the path.

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution: just remove `"credsStore": "secretservice"` from ~/.docker/config.json

Comment: It is a dangerous solution since in this way the password is stored unencrypted

Answer (score 5):

The problem for me were solved by running the script with sudo!

```
sudo docker login -u YOU-USERNAME
```

Comment: --ignore-depends=golang-docker-credential-helpers golang-docker-credential-helpers this should be run before this command to work

Answer (score 3):

For me `docker push` failed with

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

... so I wanted to `docker login` but got the following after entering credentials:

```
Remote error from secret service:
  org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod:
  No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection' on object at path
  /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login

Error saving credentials:
  error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out:
  No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection' on object at path
  /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login
```

Luckily, I had another machine available on which I was able to log in without any changes to the system. I copied the content of `~/.docker/config.json`...

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "<some-hash-value>"
                }
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.09.2 (linux)"
        }
}
```

... to the other machine and `docker push` worked.

Answer (score 2):

Just Try it: `sudo apt install golang-docker-credential-helpers`

Comment: One earlier answer already mentions this installation. What information does your answer add ?

Answer (score 1):

Well you already read solution but the fact is gnupg2 is now not installed by default in Ubuntu 18+, That is the reason sometime after `apt upgrade` , things behave a little differently.

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer I had the several issues.

1. The key generation was stuck at entropy (step 5.2).

Fortunately, the fix is easy and you only need to install the package `rng-tools`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32941065

2. On `pass init <key>` (step 5.3) the error `gpg: decryption failed: No secret key` showed up.

In fact this issue is due to the secret key being restricted to root privileges.

I changed the ownership of the `.gnupg .password-store` folders in my user's homedir.

Then reloaded the dirmngr to avoid "unsafe ownership" warning:

```sh
gpgconf --kill dirmngr
```

If you don't want to do all that you can run all commands of the answer as root/sudo.

Answer (score 1):

To me
Ubuntu 20.04

`sudo apt install golang-docker-credential-helpers`

It is working

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a credentials store. Try using Gnome Keyring; depending on your linux installation, it might already be installed. You can use GK to securely store auth data in Chrom{e,ium} (and probably more) too. Getting back to Docker, you'd need a .docker/config.json like:

```
{
    "credsStore": "secretservice"
}
```

Then, make sure you've configured PAM to unlock the keyring: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#PAM_method

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install gnupg2 pass` wasn't working for me and I was using docker without adding sudo in front everytime. So I added
`sudo docker login -u <myusername>`
it prompted me the pass and this time it worked since I used sudo for my docker.

Answer (score 0):

If you somehow still stuck in this issue, try:

```bash
sudo docker login <site>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on ubuntu 20.04:

First of all restart your docker desktop.
If not succeeded then:
Remove config by running this command:

```
rm ~/.docker/config.json
```

now

```
docker login
```

if still unable to login then try reinstalling you docker-desktop

Answer (score 0):

To me, on OpenSUSE Linux the solution was to install ***gnome-keyring***:

```
sudo zypper in gnome-keyring
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, uninstalling the package `docker-compose` and manually installing a more recent version solved the issue.

Uninstalled docker-compose :

```
sudo apt remove docker-compose
```

Installed more recent version as indicated here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-docker-compose-on-debian-10 :

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Answer (score -2):

creating the following solved it for me:

```
AWS_CONFIG=$AWS_DIR/config
AWS_CREDENTIALS=$AWS_DIR/credentials
mkdir -p $AWS_DIR
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case, this error was resolved after giving read and write access to all users to the file /var/run/docker.sock:

```sh
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score -3):

Install the following Packages in ubuntu

```
sudo apt install gnupg2 pass
```

This is worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't provide any addition to earlier answers with the same or better content.