# docker login timeout on ubuntu `Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets: Timeout was reached`

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, vmware-workstation

I have encountered this error while doing a simple `sudo docker login`. On checking the logs using `journalctl -xe` I found the following problem.

```
Jun 05 01:51:30 ubuntu sudo[24492]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)`

Jun 05 01:51:34 ubuntu dbus-daemon[7120]: [session uid=0 pid=7118] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.secrets' requested by ':1.41' (uid=0 pid=24502 comm="docker-credential-secretservice stostore " label="unconfined")`

Jun 05 01:51:34 ubuntu gnome-keyring-daemon[24511]: couldn't create socket directory: /home/aliicp/.cache/keyring-KUIFKZ: Permission denied`

Jun 05 01:51:34 ubuntu gnome-keyring-daemon[24511]: couldn't bind to control socket: /home/aliicp/.cache/keyring-KUIFKZ/control: Permission denied`

Jun 05 01:51:34 ubuntu gnome-keyring-d[24511]: couldn't create socket directory: /home/aliicp/.cache/keyring-KUIFKZ: Permission denied`

Jun 05 01:51:34 ubuntu gnome-keyring-d[24511]: couldn't bind to control socket: /home/aliicp/.cache/keyring-KUIFKZ/control: Permission denied
Jun 05 01:51:59 ubuntu sudo[24492]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root`

Jun 05 01:53:34 ubuntu dbus-daemon[7120]: [session uid=0 pid=7118] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.secrets': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
```

the keyring value set from command is `ps aux | grep keyring`:

```
aliicp    24044  0.0  0.3 288356  7944 pts/0    Sl+  00:29   0:00 gnome-keyring-daemon --start --replace --foreground --components=secrets,ssh,pcks11

aliicp    24103  0.0  0.0  21536  1016 pts/2    S+   00:33   0:00 grep --color=auto keyring
```

this problem doesn't happen when I am using `VirtualBox` or `Kitmatic` instead of `VMware`. My base OS is Win7.

Thanks.

Comment: are you behind a proxy? do you an error when you try to pull an image?

Comment: I don't think I am. Command `env | grep -i proxy` doesn't return anything. I cannot perform push into my repo which is what I am interested in. Pull from community will work regardless of the login.

Comment: I used command `startx` and it opened up a new root terminal. I can potentially login to docker now but this doesn't look like a very viable option. I am not that proficient on linux by the way.

Comment: Answer to this question solved the same problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151833/cannot-login-to-docker-account

Answer (score 5):

You could add yourself to the `docker` group. Doing so would allow docker to access your keyring and thus remove the error.

That is, on Linux,

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

Comment: This solution solved the problem for me. Thank you.
The required steps are:
[1] sudo usermod -a -G docker your-user-name
[2] Now you can run docker without sudo. It should work.