# Getting Error while connection Nexus via docker host

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I have configured Sonatype nexus in docker and trying to Docker login from other host while doing so getting the below error.

docker login -u  -p  http://:

Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets: Timeout was reached`

Comment: docker login -u -p http://<nexushost>:<port>

Comment: Sounds the same as this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151833/cannot-login-to-docker-account