# docker - permanently store docker-credential-helpers credentials

Tags: docker, credentials

looking at this: [Cannot login to Docker account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151833/cannot-login-to-docker-account)

Which I was successfully able to configure.  However, this particular part

**Note: If you get the error "pass store is uninitialized" in future run, run the below command (it will reload the pass store in memory):**

```
pass show docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check**
```

**Question:**

How do you make this permanent? So that it doesn't require authentication periodically?