# Heroku deploy with Docker, can not login?

Tags: docker, heroku

Following some tutorials, on Windows 7, I installed the Heroku CLI (first Git, then Heroku-x64). Git has several options to select during installation, I kept it default for most of them, except the editor and the interface: my choice is mintty. In mintty I changed my Git username and email.

After installing Heroku-x64, mintty still does not support the `heroku` command. And there's nothing to run in Heroku-x64's folder, so I use system's `cmd.exe` instead, and it supports the `heroku` command.

Now, following tutorials, I run `heroku container:login`, several seconds later it says

```
! not logged in
```

Shouldn't it ask me to input my Heroku username and password?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`heroku container:login`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-container-login) is for logging into the [Heroku *container registry*](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime). You probably want to use [`heroku login`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-auth-login) instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo heroku auth:login
```

then

```
sudo heroku container:login
```

use sudo for CLI login and then for container login, it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you are logged in on your Heroku CLI first:

```
heroku auth:login
```

Then you can login to your Heroku container registry:

```
heroku container:login
```

Running heroku/7.47.* on Ubuntu 20+ (WSL) might require `sudo` for both commands listed above.

Before all these, I installed `gnupg2` and `pass`, following the answer here [Cannot login to Docker account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151833/cannot-login-to-docker-account) by [Anish Varghese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8516780/anish-varghese)

Answer (score 1):

I, too, had the same issue.
Running **heroku/7.47.3** on **Ubuntu 20.04**

Make sure you are running as administrator while working on Windows.

Try logging in with CLI, by help of `heroku login -i`
and then try `heroku container:login`

Answer (score 1):

I had problem login with the other methods, but this worked fine:

```
docker login --username=_ --password=$(heroku auth:token) registry.heroku.com
```