# Error with docker-compose file for vernemq and nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, mqtt-vernemq

I wrote a docker-compose file to run two services vernemq and nginx. When i run the command docker-compose up on my terminal, i keep on getting the error below. 
If this might help, i am using a virtual machine with the ubuntu 18.04 image

I tried leaving the IP address away in the vernemq service but it didn't help.

Here is my docker compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  vernemq:
    image: erlio/docker-vernemq:1.8.0
    hostname: vernemq
    container_name: vernemq
    expose:
      - "1883"
      - "9001"
    ports:
      - "IPaddress:1883:1883"
      - "IPaddress:9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./configvol:/etc/vernemq
      - ./datavol:/var/lib/vernemq
      - ./logvol:/var/log/vernemq
    network_mode: "host"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.16.0
    hostname: nginx
    container_name: robotWebView
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginxvol:/usr/share/nginx/html
    network_mode: "host"
```

and this is the error i get

```
    # docker-compose up
    Pulling vernemq (erlio/docker-vernemq:1.8.0)...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 80, in _execute
      File "subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
      File "subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice', 'get']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 264, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 35, in get
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 93, in _execute
dockerpycreds.errors.StoreError: Credentials store docker-credential-secretservice exited with "Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets: Timeout was reached".

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 127, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1085, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1081, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 527, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 354, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1222, in pull
  File "compose/progress_stream.py", line 102, in get_digest_from_pull
  File "compose/service.py", line 1187, in _do_pull
  File "site-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 381, in pull
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 48, in get_config_header
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 322, in resolve_authconfig
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 235, in resolve_authconfig
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 281, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-secretservice exited with "Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets: Timeout was reached".',)
[10433] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151833/cannot-login-to-docker-account

Comment: Thanks, that helped me solve my problem