# `aws ecr get-login-password` `docker login` The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

This used to work:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin "$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com"
```

Now, I get:

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.``
```

If I run just `aws ecr get-login-password`, I get a successful result, which suggests I have the right AWS access:

```sh
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | base64 -d | jq '.'
{
  "payload": "redacted",
  "datakey": "redacted",
  "version": "2",
  "type": "DATA_KEY",
  "expiration": redacted
}
```

This command that is failing is in a script that has been run successfully many times before and hasn't been changed. Has something changed in new versions of Docker that would break this? Or new versions of the Amazon CLI client? One possibility, is my AWS account privileges have changed, but I would have expected the above `get-login-password` command to have not succeeded in that case.

This login method is documented here, and I seem to be following instructions exactly:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: have you found any solutions for this?

Comment: The solution on this post helped me :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151833/cannot-login-to-docker-account